# remove hover effect from add to cart button using HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, cart, mousehover

I am working on an E commerce application but the theme i am using add to cart button coming on hover effect but i want to make ( Add to cart button) always fixed .

the  live working url is as following.

https://www.realfarmer.in/techy-new/shop.php

add to cart will come when cursor is on the product but i want it should come always

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the styles under

```
.product-wrap .product-img .product-action-2-wrap {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: -20px;
}
```

Which is hiding the add to cart button if not hovered. Or you can replace the same using

```
.product-wrap .product-img .product-action-2-wrap {
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

So this is the code that's working when you hover over the product.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your add custom code

```
.product-action-2-wrap{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

this will show add to cart button always visible in the products.

if it is work for you please give a like.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the background color on Hover using same color like that:

```
.product-wrap .product-img .product-action-2-wrap:hover .product-action-btn-2 {
background-color: #000;
```

}